# What is the purpose of adding a positive variable?

Tags: java

I am currently in Java1 this semester, and I asked my teacher a question, that he could not really answer, because he didn't really know why.  Or rather couldn't think of what purpose it would serve.

Let us say that, when setting variables `a=5` and `b=-4`.  And I wanted to know the value of `a+b` set to `System.out.println`.

I could do `a + b`, but I could also do `a + + b`, which means add a to the positive `b`.  Although `b` is negative the positive variable is still negative 4.

However, if I change the equation to `a - - b`, it should come out to `b` being a positive 4.

So my question, is what is really the purpose of creating an equation for a positive variable if the positive variable, is just the variable.

Comment: I have literally never seen `a + + b` before. I thought it would be invalid, but is apparently valid. So what's the purpose of allowing it? Perhaps in some cases it might make the intent of the code clearer. I can't think of one where it would, though.

Comment: @zero298 It's the ["unary plus operator"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3)

Comment: As i stated, only for compatibility, but you downvoted, so good lucky

Answer (score -1):

Since the opposite is valid (adding to a negative such a + - b) then the sign plus doesnt affects its value.